# Is there a way to convert an IAsyncOperation to System.IO.Steam?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, stream, windows-8.1

I have a list of StorageFiles for my Windows 8 app. I need to submit them to a server via the Stream class. I've tried converting the Storage files like this:

```
Stream fs = temp[i].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
```

temp[] is the list of StorageFiles that I have containing images. Obviously that code I have doesn't work. The error message suggests I might be missing a cast or something. Is there anyway to convert the StorageFiles or IAsyncOperation to a Stream?

Comment: and what's the error message that you get?

Comment: You need to `await` it.

Comment: await doesn't do anything to it. And this is the error message:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream>' to 'System.IO.Stream'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: perhaps it's not working because it's blowing off too much `STEAM` inyour `System.IO.Steam`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
Stream fs = (await temp[i].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)).AsStream();
```

You have all the information in your error message - `OpenAsync` returns (after you `await` it) `IRandomAccessStream`, you can convert it to `System.IO.Stream` with [AsStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965622(v=vs.110).aspx) method.